# Calculating roots of $x^3 = 2x^2 - x$, getting wrong result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, roots, cubics

I am working with a text book problem, trying to find the solutions to $x^3 = 2x^2 - x$, but I keep ending up with a different result than the book gives. I'm thinking the problem lie in getting the wrong square root towards the end, seeing as the text book gives different results for $x_1$ and $x_2$, but I can't find any mistakes.

$$x^3 = 2x^2 - x$$
$$\iff x^2 = 2x - 1$$
$$\iff x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$$
$$\iff (x - \frac{2}{2})^2 = (\frac{2}{2})^2 - 1$$
$$\iff (x - 1)^2 = 0$$
$$\iff x - 1 = \pm \sqrt{0}$$
$$\iff x = 1 + \pm \sqrt{0}$$
$$\iff x = 1 + \pm 0$$
$$x_1 = 1 + 0 = 1$$
$$x_2 = 1 - 0 = 1$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that by dividing by $x$, you are implicitly assuming that $x$ is not $0$. It turns out that this is a solution. You can check this directly.

You are right that $1$ is a double root of the equation. If you move everything to one side and factor, you find that

$$x^3-2x^2+x=x(x-1)(x-1)=0$$

which confirms our answer.

Comment: Thanks! It never struck me that $x$ could be $0$ and that I discounted that possibility so easily.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $+x$ instead of $+1$? (It's too few characters for me to edit.)

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can not just divide by $x$, since $x$ could be $0$.
You have $x^3=2x^2-x$, which is equivalent to:
$$0=x^3-2x^2+x=x(x^2-2x+1)=x(x-1)^2$$
Hence $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution $x=1$ perfectly well solves $x^3 = 2x^2 - x$, as you can easily check yourself (did you try?). But so does $x=0$, a possibility that you lost along the way (can you see where?). If your book gives any other solutions, you can check that they *don't* solve the equation. Checking solutions is much easier than finding them, you should always do it for the solutions found.

Comment: I did actually try $x=1$ in the original equation, but were confused as I was supposed to find two separate for $x$. I didn't even stop to think it could be $0$. Thanks!